# How to stop a jquery function from executing

Tags: jquery

I'm centering a div on window resize but the function is still executing even though i have an 'else' statement. It's not changing to margin-top: 0. The flexVerticalCenter(); keep overriding it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $(window).on("resize", function (e) {
            checkScreenSize();
        });

        checkScreenSize();

        function checkScreenSize(){
            var newWindowWidth = $(window).width();
            if (newWindowWidth < 1023) {
                $('.v-align').flexVerticalCenter();
            }
            else {
                $('.v-align').css('margin-top', '0');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This problem happens when you are decreasing the screen witdh?

Comment: have you tried return;

Comment: also $('.v-align').css('margin-top', '0'); try to write as $('.v-align').css({'margin-top': '0'});

Comment: what does `flexVerticalCenter()` does?

Comment: It works just fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wa74ncbu/) so you probably have something that overwrites it but we can't tell unless you share all the code.

Comment: flexVerticalCenter() will take the parents height, the elements own height and calculate the distance the element should have from the parents top to be vertically centered. This value is applied to the top margin of the element by default. https://github.com/PaulSpr/jQuery-Flex-Vertical-Center

Comment: I replied to Icewine's answer with a better [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mph9g4wj/). It happens when you try to resize up from 600px breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

commenting out the items in the if else statement shows that the checkScreenSize is working so probably something in your flexVerticalCenter function or some other css overwriting.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $(window).on("resize", function (e) {
            checkScreenSize();
        });

        checkScreenSize();

        function checkScreenSize(){
            var newWindowWidth = $(window).width();
            if (newWindowWidth < 1000) {
                //$('.v-align').flexVerticalCenter();
                console.log("do the flexVerticalCenter()");
            }
            else {
                //$('.v-align').css('margin-top', '0');
                console.log("do the margin-top");
            }
        }
        
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Here is an example of the problems I'm experiencing. It happens when you resize up: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mph9g4wj/)